# Multiple SQL commands that should only execute if they all pass

Tags: sql

So I want to do 2 SQL inserts into different tables.

One insert into table A, one insert into table B.

I insert into table A first, and then in to table B.

I want to make sure that if for whatever reason the insert into table B fails (which is never should) then the insert into table A is rolled back.

What's the recommended way to do, also why do I never seem to see this in any example code?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called a `transaction` and most databases support explicit transactions.

Sample syntax is:

```
begin transaction
    insert into tableA . . . 
    insert into tableB . . .
commit transaction;
```

The specific syntax might vary by database.  But the meaning is the same:  either the entire transaction succeeds or it fails.

Comment: Thanks, follow up question: Should I reuse the same SqlCommand or use a new one? Also, in my case I am actually using the returned id from the table A in my insert into table B ( I use ExecuteScalar() for this ). Does this method still work for me?

Comment: @S.Lukas . . . I don't understand the first question.  The second is about capturing the id, which is fine.  The details depend on the database.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `Transaction` and that's why transaction is for. To provide atomacity. A sample code would be

```
create procedure usp_insert
as
begin

begin transaction
insert into tableB ....;
insert into tableA ....;

commit;

if error
rollback;
end
```